# Having an issue understanding the Scipy or OpenCV Median Filter function

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, median

I am currently writing something on Median filters and want to use some Python functions to create examples. I have an example image with the following pixels:

```
[[255   0   0   0 158]  
 [  0 158 158 158 158]  
 [  0   0 255   0   0]  
 [  0   0   0   0 158]  
 [  0 255   0   0 158]]
```

and the Python results look like this:

```
[[158   0   0 158 158]
 [  0   0   0 158 158]
 [  0   0   0 158 158]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0 158]]
```

My issue now is understanding how exactly this result is created (I'm checking a 3x3 radius) as from my understanding the very first pixel (the 255 at position 0,0) should have the result 0 because the missing pixels around it are padded with 0's. If I check it manually, I'd think with the padding we are looking at:

```
0   0   0
0 255   0
0   0 158
```

so the ordered data would be [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 158, 255] and therefore the Median should be 0. How is the result 158? A similar confusion is for many of the other values. I read on the working of the Median in "Digital Signal Processing" from Lizhe Ta and Jean Jiang. The chapters ("13.4.2 Median Filtering" and "Example 13.8") can be found here https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/median-filter

I call the filter functions like this:
Imports:

```py
import cv2
from scipy import ndimage
```

Codesnippet:

```py
median = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
print(median)
im_med = ndimage.median_filter(gray, 3)
print(im_med)
```

Since I want to write my own filter function, it is essential for me to understand exactly how all this works!

Comment: Your zero padding assumption is wrong. According to [medianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) documentation: "The median filter uses **BORDER_REPLICATE** internally to cope with border pixels".

Comment: @Rotem ah okay, so the highlighted area would become [[255, 255, 0], [255, 255, 0], [ 0,  0, 158]] instead of [[0, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 158]]? Thanks a million!